# '?' char in directory listing. How to list contents

Tags: linux

I have a listing of a directory which contains this entry:

`d????????? ? ?   ?              ?            ? dir_name`

I can't get into it, even as root. How to access?

Comment: Where is that directory located? This looks like the OS is not able to access it. Like a remote connection (NFS?) or a drive that's disconnected.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/65616/question-marks-showing-in-ls-of-directory-io-errors-too

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
chown root "? dir_name"
chmod 755 "? dir_name"
ls -lha "? dir_name"
```